# binary search, count duplicates

Tags: java

I have sorted array

```
{1,2,3,5,5,5,7,8,8}
```

I would like to count how many times the number that i am sending is found in the array in longn only.

for example:

```
public static int count(int[] array,5)
```

will reply 3

```
public static int count(int[] array,8)
```

will reply 2

so my plan is:

1) to do a binary search to find the number

2) binary search the top border index and the bottom border index.

3) print (top index - bottom index) will give me the time of target number in the array.

Is my code is logn ?
Please help! :)

```
    public class binarySearch
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.println("d");
        int[]data={1,1,2,3,1,1,1};
        System.out.println(count(data,1));
    }

    public static int count(int[] a, int x)
    {
        int low=0;
        int high = a.length-1;
        int count=0;

        while(low <=high)
        {
            int mid=((low+high)/2);         
            if(x>a[mid])
                low=mid+1;
            if(x<a[mid])
                high=mid-1;

            if(x==a[mid])            
            {
                int top=findTopIndex(a,x,mid);                
                int bottom=findBottomIndex(a,x,mid);
                return (top-bottom);

            }

        }    
        return 111111111;

    }

    public static int findTopIndex(int[] a, int x, int index)
    {
        int low=index;
        int high = a.length-1;    
        int mid;
        if(x==a[high])
        return high;

        while(low <= high)
        {            
           mid=((low+high)/2);         
           if(x<a[mid]&&x==a[mid-1])
           return mid-1;
           else if(x==a[mid])
                low=mid+1;
           else if(a[mid]>x && a[mid-1]!=x)
           high=mid-1;


        } 
        return 11111111;

    }
    public static int findBottomIndex(int[] a, int x, int index)
    {
        int low=0;
        int high = index-1;    
        int mid;
        if(x==a[low])
        return low-1;

        while(low <= high)
        {            
         mid=((low+high)/2);         
           if(x>a[mid]&&x==a[mid+1])
           return mid;
           else if(x==a[mid])
                high=mid-1;
           else if(a[mid]<x && a[mid+1]!=x)
           low=mid+1;

        } 
        return 111;

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you *need* to search for the border indices with binary search? Seems that it'd be fast enough if you continue with a linear search after that.

Comment: Use else if instead of if if if...

Comment: @millimoose what for `{1,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,8}`?

Comment: @AlvinWong Depends on exactly how likely the scenario is with your data sets. Worst-case linear complexity isn't exactly terrible. You're also assuming that it's also possible to find the edges of that run of fives efficiently.

Comment: @millimoose then linear search will save more time.

Comment: @millimoose by performing two additional binary searches complexity is still O(log(n)) and you solve all scenarios even the worst-case one.

Comment: Can you use a different data structure? PriorityQueue, SortedMap etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written is really close to the solution you need. You first do a binary search to find a single instance of the number you are searching for(let's say its found on position `index`) and then you do two more binary searches -one for the sequence `0, index`, and one for `index, size` to find up to where in both sequences is the number found.

So I suggest you simply pass an index to both `findTopIndex` and `findBottomIndex` and make use of it. I can write the whole solution but it will be better for you to come to it on your own.

Comment: This is a good approach, I totally missed the O(logn) part on my (deleted) answer. A list full of the same elements results in O(n).

Comment: If there's a very long run of the same number, couldn't the "two more" searches also land somewhere in the middle of the respective two halves of said run? Seems like you'd want to search recursively to find the top and bottom indices - i.e. when you can't find the number anymore to the left of the current index, the current index is the beginning of the run. (And vice versa.)

Comment: @millimoose no, the two additional binary searches are performed in a different manner as to find the first position differing from x. The monotonous property I use for those searches is `equal to x` and by doing a single binary search one could find the single index where this property changes from 0 to 1.